# DLL and Name Mangling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, name-decoration

I have a third-party LIB which has symbols exported as plain C/cdecl, so for example `dumpbin.exe /SYMBOLS` reports that both `__imp_nvmlInit` and `nvmlInit` are exported.

However in Visual Studio 2010 when I try to import them, the header file will have

```
extern "C" nvmlReturn_t nvmlInit(...);
```

but when I try to compile, I get the following error:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _nvmlInit referenced in function _main

How can I stop Visual Studio from looking for that symbol with a leading underscore? `__declspect(dllimport)` doesn't work because then it decorates to `__imp__nvmlInit` (one underscore too many).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is a linker error. You need to link with the .LIB file associated with DLL, which will give the linker  a promise that the function will be available at run-time when the DLL itself is loaded.

Comment: Oops, sorry I made a mistake in my original post -- I am actually linking to the .LIB, and the library exports completely undecorated functions whereas the linker is looking for underscore prepended names...