# Name mangling and dumpbin

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, intel-mkl

Yesterday I was helping a friend to compile [Intel's MKL](http://www.intel.com/software/products/mkl/) Java examples. We were having issues with "unresolved externals", even though everything seemed fine (accordingly to the example files / makefile).

I then used Visual Studio's [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to check whether the unresolved functions were present in the library. One example of a unresolved external was a function called `_cblas_sgemm`. When dumping the symbols from the library (`dumpbin /symbols mkl_core.lib`), I was only able to find a function `cblas_sgemm` on the library, which missed the prefix `_`. I then discovered that the function actually was only called cblas_sgemm, and that the compiler added the `_` prefix, as part of the name mangling rule.

**TL;DR**

So, my questions are:

1. Does `dumpbin` displays the full name of the entry point in the library? Or for some reason it actually "unmangles" the name?
2. The library came with the installation package, so I don't know which compiler was used to compile it. Does different compilers produce different names?

I don't really think I got it right; I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere else, but I want to be sure about those two questions.

A similar question with no answers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960717/dll-and-name-mangling).

Comment: Sounds to me you're trying to link the Fortran version.

Comment: @HansPassant, can you elaborate...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `dumpbin` will show the full name of symbol in the library(not in the source), without any alternation. For MS mangled of C++ names, it will show the original symbol in parenthesis (if it can figure out the original symbol). (tested with dumpbin 9.00.21022.08)
2. Different compilers do generate different symbols, especially for C++ symbols. For symbols, compilers tend to have an agreement about name mangling, so `extern "C"` symbols can be linked between different compilers.

Here is an wikipedia article about [name mangling](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll try to figure out if there's a problem with the library, after all.